# What strings are allowed to represent colors in Qt stylesheets?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I am trying to change the color of some labels in pyqt5 by setting their style sheets like so:

```css
background-color : lightblue
```

My problem is I don't know what colors I am allowed to use. For example, 'lightblue' works but 'lightred' does not. Is there some sort of lookup table somewhere with accepted color string values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [QColor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#details) documentation explains, it follows the SVG color names specification, and the Qt stylesheet parser follows the same rule.

You can find the whole list of available colors in the ["Recognized color keyword names" chapter](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords) of the SVG 1.0 specification.